# Kali Linux ACPI Error

Tags: linux, kali-linux, log

he comprado un portatil MSI Modern 15 A5M y he instalado kali linux y resulta que **tarda mucho en detectar el cargador**, **el brillo se cambia solo**, **he tenido que configurar manualmente el adaptador de red y el bluetooth funciona solo si lo invoco**

al ejecutar `sudo dmesg |grep Error` me aparece lo siguiente:

```
[    0.327948] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[    0.327956] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    1.334431] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GP17.MP2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    1.334469] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GPIO._EVT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

tambien aparecen en el check de dispositivos al encender el ordenador

estoy un poco perdido con el tema logs, he empezado a estudiar informatica y necesito linux porque es lo que utilizamos diariamente.

alguien sabria curar estos errores del comando anterior? he visto por otros foros en ingles y español que la gente o los ignora directamente o crea ciertas reglas para que el grub no le de estos errores

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Tiene que ser Kali linux? Podrías comenzar por una distro diferente; Kali tiene una audiencia muy específica y por lo que describes, no estás familiarizado con el entorno *nix. Por qué no pruebas algo más amable para comenzar, como Ubuntu, Linux Mint o algún otro?

Comment: toma en cuenta lo que dice el amjgo arriba, uso kali linux hace 7 años y la verdad es un excelente sistema operativo, pero el problema es que demora en obtener controladores, especificamente de equipos nuevos, como es tu caso(y como fue en el mio con la wifi),   quizas podrias resinatalar los drivers completos y los de la grafica igual,  si esque tiene.

Comment: la verdad muchas gracias a ambos, y si, parece que kali tarda en implementar ciertos drivers y firm en sus nucleos, por tanto acabare haciendo lo que dice @Alfabravo y terminare renunciando a kali por un ubuntu (aunque no es plato de mi gusto) pero hay que reconocer que tiene mayor soporte y compatibilidad HW

Comment: Prueba y comienza aprendiendo sin preocuparte por los básicos. Cuando estés más familiarizado, podrás buscar soluciones para las cosas y recompilar cosas sin lío, personalizando tu distribución a tu gusto.